# Redis transaction is blocking all other requests

Tags: redis

There's one thing I don't get when reading redis transaction docs:

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed
> sequentially. **It can never happen that a request issued by another
> client is served in the middle of the execution** of a Redis
> transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a
> single isolated operation.

From: https://redis.io/topics/transactions

The fragment in bold is the one that bugs me. Does it mean that when setting value of the key A in one request, another request that wants to set a value for the key B will be blocked until the first one finishes?

Comment: Yep - it means that.

Comment: Doesn't it kill the performance?

Comment: Not necessarily, as long as each operation is short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, opening a transaction with `MULTI` does not block other concurrent connections to redis.

https://redis.io/topics/transactions#usage

> A Redis transaction is entered using the MULTI command. The command always replies with OK. At this point the user can issue multiple commands. **Instead of executing these commands, Redis will queue them. All the commands are executed once `EXEC` is called**.

Your commands inside of a transaction are collected until you close the transaction. Afterwards the commends will be executed all at one without interruption. This means other connections can still execute their commands **before** commands of the still open transaction if they are submitted afterwards, while they are still submitted before closing the transaction.

Comment: So during the running of ```EXEC``` this becomes a blocking operation? right

Comment: yes, running `EXEC` is blocking for other commands, as Redis is single threaded any executed command should be blocking other commands during the execution. It's just that they are executed really fast, because everything is hold im memory. And running a single threaded application also avoids to create synchronisation overhead on locks, to avoid concurrent modification.